# About Lidskii's theorem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

I wonder if there was an easier way than proving Lidskii's theorem in order to show, for the particular case of $U$, compact trace class operator which is also self-adjoint to show that its eigenvalues $\displaystyle \left(\lambda_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\lambda_n=\text{Tr}\left(U\right)
$$

I was trying to prove it using linear span of the hilbert's basis and let $n \rightarrow +\infty$, isn't this possible ?

Comment: As the spectral theorem yields *("For every compact self-adjoint operator $T$, there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$")* you just evaluate the trace with respect to this orthonormal basis $(e_n)_n$ and get $\operatorname{tr}(T)=\sum_{n}\langle e_n,Te_n\rangle=\sum_{n}\lambda_n\Vert e_n\Vert^2=\sum_{n}\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $U$ is selfadjoint, it is a standard computation to show that distinct eigenvalues have orthogonal eigenspaces. The fact that $U$ is trace-class guarantees that all eigenspaces (with the possible exception of zero) are finite-dimensional.

When the above is put together, you get the *Spectral Theorem*: there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ such that 
$$
U=\sum_n\lambda_n\langle \cdot,e_n\rangle\,e_n. 
$$
And now you can calculate the trace using that particular orthonormal basis: since $Ue_n=\lambda_ne_n$, 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(U)=\sum_n\langle Ue_n,e_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle\lambda_ne_n,e_n\rangle=\sum_n\lambda_n. 
$$